# Fetching the specific columns JPA, Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

I am working on fetching the specific columns and then stored their values in **String** var. 
If I am using `List<String> var = new ArrayList<>();` then it works well. But actually I don't need the `List<String>`   I just need only one `String var` to store the value. The code I'm currently using.

```
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> address = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Connection connection = connectionService.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select name,address from students where students_id=" + students_id + "");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                name.add(rs.getString("name"));
                address.add(rs.getString("address"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.toString());

        }
```

> If I replace the `List<String> name` with `String name` then it gives me the error **resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set**.
>   How could I do the expected.

Comment: The error and the code in the post are not matching

Comment: No, that's nt what causes the error. The error is caused by the fact that you try to call rs.getString() before calling rs.next(). FYI, you're using JDBC, not JPA. And you completely missed the point of prepared statements, which is to safely pass parameters. Google for "JDBC prepared statements tutorial" and read how to pass parameters. Ignoring exceptions and not closing connections are also terrible ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use a repository like this

```
@Query("SELECT new map ( s.name as name, s.address as address) FROM Students s where s.studentsId = ?1")
List<Students> getAllStudents(long id);
```